# unable to load MediaInfo Library

Tags: c#

Am using Mediainfo library in my C# project,before start invoking this dll,i just ran VC++ program that comes with the package and deployed in to my local system.am not sure what exactly it did when it deploys,it register something in the system,so my process can identify the mediainfo.dll,so it worked well in my local (32bit).

When i start deploying in Testserver,i can't run or deploy the VC++(bcoz test server don't have visual studio to do that,except debugger).so am getting this error

```
 public class MediaInfo
{
    //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)  

    [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_New();


    //MediaInfo class

    public String Inform()
    {
        if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
            return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
        if (MustUseAnsi)
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
        else
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
    }
    public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch)
    {
        if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
            return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
        if (MustUseAnsi)
        {
            IntPtr Parameter_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Parameter);
            String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter_Ptr, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Parameter_Ptr);
            return ToReturn;
        }
        else
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
    }
    public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo)
    {
        if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
            return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
        if (MustUseAnsi)
            return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
        else
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
    }
    public String Option(String Option, String Value)
    {
        if (Handle == (IntPtr)0)
            return "Unable to load MediaInfo library";
        if (MustUseAnsi)
        {
            IntPtr Option_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Option);
            IntPtr Value_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Value);
            String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Option(Handle, Option_Ptr, Value_Ptr));
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Option_Ptr);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Value_Ptr);
            return ToReturn;
        }
        else
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Option(Handle, Option, Value));
    }
    public int State_Get() { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_State_Get(Handle); }
    public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { if (Handle == (IntPtr)0) return 0; return (int)MediaInfo_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
    private IntPtr Handle;
    private bool MustUseAnsi;

    //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
    public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
    public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
    public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
    public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
    public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(StreamKind, -1); }
}
```

Just google thru SourceForge.net found this https://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/forums/forum/297610/topic/4037237 but still i don't know what they are suggesting.

look like they ask to import the com object but anyone please guide me how to import the com object in C# ?

Some how its fail to import the dll,is this any other way to import or just give the path to find the dll ?

like

```
PathToMediaInfoDLL := "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\autohotkey\MediaInfo.dll"
```

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To run MediaInfo in c# you don't need to run any VC++. Just download binaries. But you need to remeber about few things:

*First: Use correct version of mediainfo.dll x32 or x64.*

*Second: The path were media library is needs to be visible by system. So or MediaInfo.dll is in the same folder as application, or folder is added to system paths.*

*Third: Use attached to library c# wrapper class for easier interop.*

Below is the proper wrapper class dowloaded from source forge:

```
// MediaInfoDLL - All info about media files, for DLL
// Copyright (C) 2002-2009 Jerome Martinez, Zen@MediaArea.net
//
// This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
// License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
// version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
// Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
// MediaInfoDLL - All info about media files, for DLL
// Copyright (C) 2002-2009 Jerome Martinez, Zen@MediaArea.net
//
// This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
// modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
// License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
// version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
//
// This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
// but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
// MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
// Lesser General Public License for more details.
//
// You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
// License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
// Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307  USA
//
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//
// Microsoft Visual C# wrapper for MediaInfo Library
// See MediaInfo.h for help
//
// To make it working, you must put MediaInfo.Dll
// in the executable folder
//
//+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MediaInfoLib
{
    public enum StreamKind
    {
        General,
        Video,
        Audio,
        Text,
        Chapters,
        Image
    }

    public enum InfoKind
    {
        Name,
        Text,
        Measure,
        Options,
        NameText,
        MeasureText,
        Info,
        HowTo
    }

    public enum InfoOptions
    {
        ShowInInform,
        Support,
        ShowInSupported,
        TypeOfValue
    }

    public enum InfoFileOptions
    {
        FileOption_Nothing      = 0x00,
        FileOption_NoRecursive  = 0x01,
        FileOption_CloseAll     = 0x02,
        FileOption_Max          = 0x04
    };


    public class MediaInfo
    {
        //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)  
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_New();
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void   MediaInfo_Delete(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FileName);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Handle, Int64 File_Size, byte[] Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64  MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern Int64  MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Open_Buffer_Finalize(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void   MediaInfo_Close(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Option(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Option, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoA_Option(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr Option,  IntPtr Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_State_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfo_Count_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber);

        //MediaInfo class
        public MediaInfo()
        {
            Handle = MediaInfo_New();
            if (Environment.OSVersion.ToString().IndexOf("Windows")==-1)
                MustUseAnsi=true;
            else
                MustUseAnsi=false;
        }
        ~MediaInfo() { MediaInfo_Delete(Handle); }
        public int Open(String FileName)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr FileName_Ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(FileName);
                int ToReturn = (int)MediaInfoA_Open(Handle, FileName_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(FileName_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return (int)MediaInfo_Open(Handle, FileName);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Init(Int64 File_Size, Int64 File_Offset)
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Init(Handle, File_Size, File_Offset);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Continue(IntPtr Buffer, IntPtr Buffer_Size)
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue(Handle, Buffer, Buffer_Size);
        }
        public Int64 Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get()
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Continue_GoTo_Get(Handle);
        }
        public int Open_Buffer_Finalize()
        {
            return (int)MediaInfo_Open_Buffer_Finalize(Handle);
        }
        public void Close() { MediaInfo_Close(Handle); }
        public String Inform()
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)0));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Parameter_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Parameter);
                String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter_Ptr, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Parameter_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch));
        }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
                return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo));
        }
        public String Option(String Option, String Value)
        {
            if (MustUseAnsi)
            {
                IntPtr Option_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Option);
                IntPtr Value_Ptr=Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(Value);
                String ToReturn=Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(MediaInfoA_Option(Handle, Option_Ptr, Value_Ptr));
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Option_Ptr);
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Value_Ptr);
                return ToReturn;
            }
            else
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfo_Option(Handle, Option, Value));
        }
        public int State_Get() { return (int)MediaInfo_State_Get(Handle); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { return (int)MediaInfo_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
        private IntPtr Handle;
        private bool MustUseAnsi;

        //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
        public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
        public int Count_Get(StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(StreamKind, -1); }
    }

















    public class MediaInfoList
    {
        //Import of DLL functions. DO NOT USE until you know what you do (MediaInfo DLL do NOT use CoTaskMemAlloc to allocate memory)  
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_New();
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfoList_Delete(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Open(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string FileName, IntPtr Options);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern void MediaInfoList_Close(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Inform(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr Reserved);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_GetI(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, IntPtr Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Parameter, IntPtr KindOfInfo, IntPtr KindOfSearch);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Option(IntPtr Handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Option, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string Value);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_State_Get(IntPtr Handle);
        [DllImport("MediaInfo.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr MediaInfoList_Count_Get(IntPtr Handle, IntPtr FilePos, IntPtr StreamKind, IntPtr StreamNumber);

        //MediaInfo class
        public MediaInfoList() { Handle = MediaInfoList_New(); }
        ~MediaInfoList() { MediaInfoList_Delete(Handle); }
        public int Open(String FileName, InfoFileOptions Options) { return (int)MediaInfoList_Open(Handle, FileName, (IntPtr)Options); }
        public void Close(int FilePos) { MediaInfoList_Close(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos); }
        public String Inform(int FilePos) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Inform(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)0)); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo, InfoKind KindOfSearch) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo, (IntPtr)KindOfSearch)); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_GetI(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber, (IntPtr)Parameter, (IntPtr)KindOfInfo)); }
        public String Option(String Option, String Value) { return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(MediaInfoList_Option(Handle, Option, Value)); }
        public int State_Get() { return (int)MediaInfoList_State_Get(Handle); }
        public int Count_Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber) { return (int)MediaInfoList_Count_Get(Handle, (IntPtr)FilePos, (IntPtr)StreamKind, (IntPtr)StreamNumber); }
        private IntPtr Handle;

        //Default values, if you know how to set default values in C#, say me
        public void Open(String FileName) { Open(FileName, 0); }
        public void Close() { Close(-1); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter, InfoKind KindOfInfo) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, KindOfInfo, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, String Parameter) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text, InfoKind.Name); }
        public String Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind, int StreamNumber, int Parameter) { return Get(FilePos, StreamKind, StreamNumber, Parameter, InfoKind.Text); }
        public String Option(String Option_) { return Option(Option_, ""); }
        public int Count_Get(int FilePos, StreamKind StreamKind) { return Count_Get(FilePos, StreamKind, -1); }
    }

} //NameSpace
```

Comment: ,thanks for your comment,can you please guide me your "Second" point.How can i find the path or how to let the process know the path where the dll is ?

Comment: You need to add path were MediaInfo is to System Enviroment Paths. _Computer->Properties->Advanced->Environment_. Sorry for lack of proper names were to look, but I don't have english os.

Comment: i might bother little bit ,sorry about that.Very few of them using this dll,you are my only hope now to work this out in my test server.In my desktop it finds.i create a setup project from my desktop and installed in my test server.it installed in c:\programfiles\CadProject. under this project i can see it has mediainfo dll but some how its not pointing out or looking somewhere else.Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: What kind of error do you have? Remember about point 1. Be sure using correct version depends on system. I'm using mediainfo.dll and incuded c# wrapper quite a lot and the only problems I had, if mediainfo.dll is in the same folder as application was related to mono (fixed by correct rebind in config file) and version missmatch using x32 on x64 system and vice versa.

Comment: Be sure you downloaded correct media info from: [SourceForge] (http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/files/binary/mediainfo/0.7.53/) eg. _MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.53_Windows_x64.zip_ or _MediaInfo_CLI_0.7.53_Windows_i386.zip_ depends on system version.

Comment: I just looked into your code again. and cannot see the place where mediainfo is initialized. I've updated answer with proper wrapper class, downloaded directly from source forge.

Comment: Thanks,Thanks,Thanks for your great help,sorry i was stuck up with another problem,so i didn't play around with mediainfo.Okie am using this wrapper class in my c#(in my local desktop) to develop my application.It works perfectly fine.That's why am wondering why it doesn't work in my test server.even i check the mediainfo.dll in the same setup folder.i will download again 64bit and go step by step to see how its working and post my result back to you.Thanks a ton again.

Comment: sorry for the late reply,just start work back on MediaInfo issues,i use the wrapper class what you gave above but i can gaurantee one thing,Media Info.dll is not visible to my system,that's why it throw's unable to load media info,can you please guide me how to find the path where the media info dll is suppose to be deployed ?thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcin,solved the issue given obsolete path in DLL import.

Answer (score 2):

simply add the "MediaInfo.dll" to the folder "YourVisualStudioProjectPath\bin\Debug\" (from VisualStudio created by Debugging; the compiled "*.exe" file is there...)