# C# Move video files into folders based on their video frame size.

Tags: c#, file-properties

I have a hard drives dedicated to videos, and I wanted to write a program that would move all my video files into folders based on their video playback size.

I was thinking about having it organized like this.

```
/HD/1080p/(FileName)/(fileName).ext
/HD/720p/(FileName)/(fileName).ext
(I know that not all video files are 1080 or 720p because of crop, but within +-20 to 30px.)
/SD/(FileName)/(fileName).ext //anything less then 720p
```

I know you are able to right click on a video file and go to properties then details and see the frame width and frame height, but I'm not sure you can view this information in C#.

I don't know where to start and some information would be awesome. like:

Moving files with c#, renaming them, Viewing file details (frame sizes, file type, name, lenght, etc.) I plan on making a DB on this information but as of right now I just want to move the files into the correct folders.

I have been doing this manually and it's very tedious and time consuming.

Any help would be awesome, Thanks,
Throdne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best for getting file info properties is to use **MediaInfo.dll**. There is also c# wrapper available to collect all data you need from video file.

You can obtain media ifo from [mediainfo.sourceforge.net](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net)

This is multiplatform and can be used on Mono and Linux as well on Windows.

I've put also some information about MediaInfo on following thread: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561490...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561490/unable-to-load-mediainfo-library/9563397#9563397)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is using something like DirectShow which will handle multiple video formats there is a com+ object you can attach to but on source forge there is a wrapper around the 
[API](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/)

[Info on sourceforge](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2615/DirectShow-NET)

once you have that figured out you can then go

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx) to figure out how to move files around