# Getting .MOV file details in C#

Tags: c#, video, fileinfo

Hello I am working on video files and would like to learn video's length, frame width and height, and total bitrate. I have seen solutions for ID3 tags but they don't seem working for movies(.mov extension)

Comment: I don't know if [TagLib#](https://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp/tree/master/src/TagLib) handles .mov but it can be worth to check out.

Answer (score 0):

Find and download/buy ISO/IEC 14496-12 (MPEG-4 Part 12)

The `mvhd` and `tkhd` boxes (and possibly others... it's been a while!) will give you the information you're looking for. The MOV file format is quite easy to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the file is playable within DirectShow, you can build a pipeline for this file and without running it check the pipeline properties to find out details like duration is resolution. This method is not specific to `.MOV` and works out well for other formats. In C# you typically interface to DirectShow via [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

See related:

- [Grab frame from .mov file using DirectShow.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102241/grab-frame-from-mov-file-using-directshow-net)
- [Getting MP4 File Duration with DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346136/getting-mp4-file-duration-with-directshow)
- [how to get the duration from a mp4 media file by C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768398/how-to-get-the-duration-from-a-mp4-media-file-by-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

In my opionion the best way is use of MediaInfo. It not requires any additional codecs installed etc.
See my answer in this post:
[unable to load MediaInfo Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561490/unable-to-load-mediainfo-library/9563397#9563397)